# Font "Myriad Pro" looks weird/fuzzy in Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I used the font "Myriad Pro" on my web page and it looks funny and weird on Chrome as compared to FF/IE/Safari.

I see the difference when font size is smaller than 23~25px range. Is there something I am missing? for example it is not a safe font to use at all? I have also read [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/350/web-safe-alternative-to-myriad-pro-font) too.

FYI my chrome version is Version 22.0.1229.79 m on a Window 7 Pro machine.

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest a workaround: Use [Vegur](http://www.fontspace.com/arro/vegur) (which is public domain) and @font-face it with [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator); in my experience, I've always run into issues with Myriad on the web (line-heights, aliasing, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in css

```
html, html a {
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);*/
     text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;

}
```